# log4j picking up wrong properties file

Tags: java, configuration, log4j

There are 2 log4j.properties files in my classpath. I need both of them - One of them is required for a library that I am using and another is the one used by my code. When I run my jar file, it is able to read the properties used by the library, but it is not reading my own properties file. How can I make it read my log4j without having to use PropertytConfigurator in all my source files? Is there any way I can configure it so that it used both the properties files together?

Comment: It will pick-up only one. Why don;t have one file two filters/appenders?

Comment: Do you have multiple categories set in your log4j?

Comment: yes I have multiple categories

Answer (score 4):

To answer your first question, you can point it to your own file by giving it a unique name and adding the following system property when you launch your application.

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=path_to_my_properties_file
```

I don't think it is possible to use 2 different files without doing anything programatically.

Answer (score 3):

Two `log4j.properties` files will surely create a mess (as you've experienced).

I'd suggest removing the library's version (why is it a requirement?), and combining both `.properties` files into one.

Answer (score 1):

All logging goes into a single property file. Within that file you can differentiate between your own classes and the library's logging configuration.