# log4j Properties File pick

Tags: java, log4j

Observed a rather strange behaviour from apache log4j and thought sharing to get your thoughts.

I have an application which I'm running using an script. So far nothing special about that.
But the CLASSPATH I'm setting using that script, say a directory */home/myName/*, have two different log4j properties files. One is simply *log4j.properties* and other is *log4jXYZ.prperties*.

The strange thing is when I run this script from different directories, one or the other log4j properties file is being picked-up. My understanding was it should have picked log4j.properties, obviously irrespectively from whereever I run the script.

Do you see some logic which can make a sense of it. Currently I'm at loss.

What I can predict is that log4j is trying any file matching lo4j*.properties expression.I must admit I haven't read all the manual assisting log4j.

Comment: why do you need both files in there? check out this answer which might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866259/log4j-picking-up-wrong-properties-file

Answer (score 1):

Add log4j.debug property, when you run the application (`-Dlog4j.debug=` for the java command), it should show you the path where it loads the config file from.

I suspect it may load a file with same name from another directory than you think.